# Non-linear system with one parameter

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a system of $2$ non-linear equations that has more than according to the variation of one parameter have $2$, $1$ or $0$ solutions. I would like to add a 3rd equation to the system so the extra variable give me as result the parameter to have only $1$ solution.

I give you an example:

$x^2 + y^2 - 0.8x + p = 0,$

$-x^2 + 2x - 2y - p^2 = 0$.

In the system above, $x$ and $y$ are the variable and $p$ is the parameter.
What equation should I add to the system to find the value of the parameter $p$ that gives me only $1$ solution of the system?

Comment: Can't there be $4$ solutions ?

Comment: No, it is a 2nd order system, so only 2, 1 or 0 solution are possible.

Comment: Wrong, two conics can intersect in four points. This is a fourth degree problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it could be… Anyway I am looking for the parameter that gives me only 1 solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the second equation and solve this one for $y$
$$y=\frac{1}{2}(-x^2+2x-p^2)$$ and plug this one in the first equation:
$$1/4\,{p}^{4}+1/2\,{p}^{2}{x}^{2}+1/4\,{x}^{4}-{p}^{2}x-{x}^{3}+2\,{x}^
{2}+p-4/5\,x
=0$$
The degree is four and the solution is not so simple.

Comment: What you propose is just a way to solve the 2 equations system, buy has nothing to do with my question. I want to add a 3rd equation with the parameter as variable to find the value of the parameter that returns only 1 solution to the first system of 2 equations.

Comment: @Mattia: you should be more cautious when declaring things like "buy has nothing to do with my question". If you can prove that this equation has a double root and a pair of complex, you are done.